# If my Pokemon faints, does it break my chain?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was shiny hunting in ORAS using the DEXnav, and my Pokemon is close to fainting.

If my Pokemon faints, does it break my chain?

Comment: what chain are you refering to?

Comment: @Timelord64 this is fairly clearly about DEXnav chaining, a method to increase the encounter rate of shiny pokemon. Although I think a better question would be "what does/doesn't break a DEXnav chain?" Rather than potentially infinite questions regarding every little thing that might break the chain.

Answer (score 6):

Chaining with DexNav in ORAS is not broken by your pokemon fainting.*NOTE

Per [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2nnrsa/qa_dexnav_chaining_and_shiny_pokemon/) (formatted for clarity)

```
What will break my chain? 
- Encountering other Pokemon WHILE NOT SNEAKING. (Use repels) 
- Leaving the route. 
- Running from battle. 
- Scaring off a Pokemon.
```

This is also supported by [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav#Chaining)

*NOTE: If it is your last/only pokemon that faints, you will be sent to the pokemon center, which breaks the chain due to leaving the route.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've seen on twitch;

- If it is your last pokémon and it faints, it counts as leaving the route, as you will black out.
- If you have more pokémon left, no. If one does faint, just make sure you have another strong pokémon in your second slot, or revive the first one.

Comment: I think this would be better listed as a comment. The only thing this adds should be common sense. If your last pokemon faints, your going to leave the route. I would suggest that if the concept is not automatic knowledge, the user is probably not far advanced in the game enough, yet, to be shiny hunting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It has been recently found out that the Dexnav method of shiny hunting **does not** involve chaining, rather you just get a higher chance of finding a shiny when you use it compared to random encounter.

This means the answer to your question is no, as no chains can be broke if they were never there in the first place.

Source: